# How to calculate the cooling jacket of a liquid propellant engine with an external component?

Tags: rockets, engines, engine-design, calculation, cooling

When designing a small rocket engine with a thrust of `100 N`, questions arose about the cooling of the combustion chamber and the nozzle apparatus. It was decided to create a cooling jacket for it during the bench tests, which will remove heat from it by pumping another liquid (**not components of the fuel pair**), but I cannot find literature with detailed calculations and examples. Could you advise me what is worth reading?